# Jenkins:ambiguous certification in /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, macos-sierra

After been update to Sierra(osx 10.12) on my mac, the jenkins could not compile ios items successfully as before. It always failed with iPhone Distribution: Haitao Song (XXXXXXXXXX): ambiguous (matches "iPhone Distribution: Haitao Song (XXXXXXXXXX)" and "iPhone Distribution: Haitao Song (XXXXXXXXXX)" in /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db.

I didn't find any expired certificates from Keychain

I have used /usr/bin/security find-identity /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db to check keychains, result as below:

> Matching identities
>
> 1) XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX "iPhone Distribution: Haitao Song (XXXXXXXXXX)"
>
> Valid identities only
>
> 1) XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX "iPhone Distribution: Haitao Song (XXXXXXXXXX)"

Who can tell me what's the differences between Matching identities and Valid identities.Can I delete one of them to eliminate ambiguous, or how can I fix this.

BTW, I have specified Code Signing Identity to Haitao Song (XXXXXXXXXX) on my xcode plugin configuration, and my xcode version is still 7.3.1

Below is Error Details, it happened at Packaging IPA.

#### Codesigning '' with 'iPhone Distribution: Haitao Song (XXXXXXXXXX)'

- /usr/bin/codesign --force --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements --sign iPhone Distribution: Haitao Song (XXXXXXXXXX) --entitlements /var/folders/wq/rn3bp1x96bn0sbxtzhvj3yk400008l/T/75lOkNdlo1/entitlements_plistgpzcqk6a /var/folders/wq/rn3bp1x96bn0sbxtzhvj3yk400008l/T/75lOkNdlo1/Payload/test.app
  Program /usr/bin/codesign returned 1 : [iPhone Distribution: Haitao Song (XXXXXXXXXX): ambiguous (matches "iPhone Distribution: Haitao Song (XXXXXXXXXX)" and "iPhone Distribution: Haitao Song (XXXXXXXXXX)" in /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db)

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** run `security find-identity -v -p codesigning`

**Step 2:** locate the lines of the CodeSigning  with `iPhone Distribution: Haitao Song (XXXXXXXXXX)`, which may look like

```
1) FF9E1C12A6FE7028211B0123450D2F9845481DE0 "iPhone Distribution: Haitao Song (XXXXXXXXXX)"
```

and `FF9E1C12A6FE7028211B0123450D2F9845481DE0` is the SHA1 of your ambiguous identities

**Step 3:** run `security delete-certificate -Z FF9E1C12A6FE7028211B0123450D2F9845481DE0` to remove the wrong identities

**Step 4:** create a new cert on [Apple Developer Center](http://developer.apple.com), download and add it to your keychain

**Step 5:** re-generate all mobile provision profiles with new cert which be generated by the old cert